# JENKINS : Is there a Jenkins Variable to get user name who did last commit in stash

Tags: jenkins, bitbucket-server

I got a task to run jenkins job for every commit in stash. And in email body I need to mentioned the user name who last pushed code in to stash.

Is there any Jenkins Variable to get user name who did last commit in stash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at **[Email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin)**. It provides a ton a features and control over the email, including what you are asking.

In particular, to display just the name of the user who committed a change, use:
`${CHANGES,  format="%a"}`

Comment: Thanks @Slav, ${CHANGES,  format="%a"} is working for me

Comment: Is it possible to show ALL Names? If there are more than one User who commited a change?