# Jenkins-Git -Retrieving commited user

Tags: git, jenkins

I want to get the user who commits in Git or other SCM tool.I am running sonarqube from jenkins for each commit(Plugin is already available) to run.But i need to  get the user for each commit before running sonarqube, so that i could show the metrics for each user with respective to technical debts,function points etc from Sonarqube.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Get the user where and show the metrics how?

Comment: I want to show data for each user who commits the code with respective to sonarqube metrics.For example If i want to know technical debts of user "A" ,once the user A commits the code in SCM i will run the Sonarqube to get the technical debts.But in a holistic approach if i want to show the technical debts for all users in SCM i have to maintain a local table to store it.So to identify tech.debts for each user i need user name or user id  to map as unique id in my local table. Thats why i need user for each commit when it happens.I am not sure how to get the user from jenkins or SCM.

Comment: I think you want the [Developer Cockpit plugin($)](http://www.sonarsource.com/products/plugins/developer-tools/developer-cockpit/)

Comment: Thanks for your comments G.Ann .But I am pulling data from SonarQube by using its API and to show in my own dashboard, Cockpit plugin wont work since its not exposing any APIs and also licensed one.                     I am looking like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24450425/jenkins-is-there-a-jenkins-variable-to-get-user-name-who-did-last-commit-in-st

Answer (score 0):

SonarQube is not the right tool for this job. It gets its committer data by running your SCM's "blame" command. If you plan to use this data external to SonarQube then you should do the same.

Comment: Many Thanks Ann.Just i am considering sonarQube to give metrics with respective to data only.But i looked for some free plugins ,which could sync with SCM (Not cockpit)which i might not aware of it.